# Permanently enable scl for RHEL6 RedHat

Tags: rhel

RedHat provides a way to install packages with newer versions of packages than officially supported with Software Collections. After the installation of a software collection it is necessary to enable the alternative version, in my case python27 on RHEL6.

```
    scl enable python27 bash
```

Is there a way to permanently enable an alternative version?